# How to optimize MySQL query with multiple identical subqueries and multiple grouping

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

## Problem statement

The two identical sub-queries (i.e., "a" and "b") are used to derive sub-query "n" which I further aggregate to get the final result. The response time of the query is not optimal, can anyone share some ideas to help optimize? I tried to comebine "a" and "b" as well as "a" and "n" but neither turns out to be dead ends per my knowledge...

```
select n.businessLiaision,
       n.channel,
       n.name,
       n.dt,
       n.ifNew,
       count(n.productRowId),
       sum(n.totalQty),
       sum(n.totalAmount)
from ( select a.productRowId,
              a.name,
              a.rowId,
              a.dt,
              a.businessLiaision,
              a.channel,
              a.ct,
              a.totalQty,
              a.totalAmount,
              case when a.ct = sum(b.ct) then 'true' else 'false' end as 'ifNew'
       from  ( select d.productRowId,
                      p.name,
                      DATE_FORMAT(o.effectiveTime, '%m/%Y') as 'dt',
                      p.rowId,
                      p.businessLiaision,
                      p.channel,
                      count(*) as 'ct',
                      sum(d.qty) as 'totalQty',
                      sum(d.amountPostDiscount) as 'totalAmount'
               from transactionParty as p 
               join transactionOrderHist as o on p.rowId = o.transactionPartyRowId
               join transactionOrderDetailHist as d on o.rowId = d.orderRowId
               where o.businessType = 'sales'
               group by d.productRowId, p.name, DATE_FORMAT(o.effectiveTime, '%m/%Y'), p.rowId, p.businessLiaision, p.channel
               ) as a
       left join ( select d.productRowId,
                          p.name,
                          DATE_FORMAT(o.effectiveTime, '%m/%Y') as 'dt',
                          count(*) as 'ct'
                   from transactionParty as p 
                   join transactionOrderHist as o on p.rowId = o.transactionPartyRowId
                   join transactionOrderDetailHist as d on o.rowId = d.orderRowId
                   where o.businessType = 'sales'
                   group by d.productRowId, p.name, DATE_FORMAT(o.effectiveTime, '%m/%Y')
                  ) as b on b.productRowId = a.productRowId and b.name = a.name and b.dt <= a.dt
        group by  a.productRowId, a.name, a.rowId, a.dt, a.ct, a.businessLiaision, a.channel, a.ct, a.totalQty, a.totalAmount
       ) as n
group by n.businessLiaision, n.channel, n.name, n.dt,  n.ifNew
```

## Explain plan result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXvlQ.png)

## Table descriptions

**transactionParty**

```
CREATE TABLE `transactionParty` ( 
`rowId` varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
`name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
`code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`businessLiaision` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
`type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
`contractualType` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
`paymentMethod` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
`partyGroup` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
`channel` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
`costCenter` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
`warehouseRowId` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
`taxOption` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`rowId`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**transactionOrderHist**

```
CREATE TABLE `transactionOrderHist` (
 `rowId` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT '明道记录ID', 
 `orderId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '单据ID', 
 `orderCreationTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '单据创建时间', 
 `orderCreator` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '单据创建人', 
 `businessType` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '业务类型', 
 `businessLiaision` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '内部业务负责人，如业务员/采购/文员', 
 `transactionPartyRowId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '往来单位', 
 `outboundWarehouse` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '发货仓', 
 `inboundWarehouse` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '收货仓', 
 `outboundWarehouseType` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `inboundWarehouseType` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `effectiveTime` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT '单据过账时间', 
 `orderEffectuater` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '单据过账人', 
 `remark` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `productCount` int(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `totalUnitCount` int(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `totalCostAmount` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `totalPostDiscountAmount` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `paymentStatus` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `paymentDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
 `outboundWarehouseRowId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `inboundWarehouseRowId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`rowId`) USING BTREE, 
 KEY `orderEffectiveDate` (`effectiveTime`) 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**transactionOrderDetailHist**

```
CREATE TABLE `transactionOrderDetailHist` ( 
 `rowId` varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
 `orderRowId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `productRowId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `qty` int(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `price` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `cost` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `amount` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `amountPostDiscount` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `effectiveTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
 `costAmount` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`rowId`) USING BTREE 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Please when asking performance questions always include explain plan and table description. Run `explain` before your query and `show create table table_name` and post both results in the question

Comment: Hey Ergest, I just added a screenshot of the explain plan result in the post. For table description I will need sometime as my current laptop doesn't have the mysql software..

Comment: @ErgestBasha I put the table descriptions on the post too. Pls check and let me know if any further data requried. Thanks!

Comment: try adding the following index `alter table transactionOrderHist add index idx_tr_bt (transactionPartyRowId,businessType);`

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM        ( SELECT ... )
[LEFT] JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ON ...
```

is notoriously inefficient.  Try to rewrite the query to avoid such.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`; meanwhile, I will do some guessing.

These indexes *may* help:

```
d:  INDEX(orderRowId,  productRowId, qty, amountPostDiscount)
o:  INDEX(businessType, transactionPartyRowId,  effectiveTime, rowId)
```

Looking at the final `GROUP BY`.  It does not necessarily order the rows.  If you want a particular order, add an `ORDER BY`.  Be aware that the `dt` part is not quite in chronological order since it has month before year.   The other group-bys are in derived tables, so an `ORDER BY` would be ignored.

If `and  b.name = a.name and  b.dt <= a.dt` is for doing "groupwise-max", that is the performance bottleneck.  There are much better ways to do it.  See [*Groupwise-Max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) .

If the text is in Chinese, you should consider converting to utf8mb4 -- utf8 is missing the 4-byte UTF-8 Chinese characters.

It is OK to have the `PRIMARY KEY` as `VARCHAR(50)`, but it could be better to use `INT`.  Is some outside process providing the rowId?

Comment: The rowId is something like '3fd43f17-6b7c-4f66-86b1-3d99929a89e3' and generated by a outside service.